# JackD mutes PulseAudio

Tags: 11.10, banshee, pulseaudio, jack, mute

I use rakarrack for guitar effects and I want to listen mp3 playback (Banshee etc.) and midi (Tuxguitar etc.). But when I start rakarack it starts JACK and JACK mutes all other sound sources except for rakarrack. I can't start JACK while Banshee or other playback program is running. JACK and pulseaudio don't seem to be working at the same time how can I fix this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I came across this a few days ago.

https://help.ubuntu.com/community/UbuntuStudioPreparation#Pulse_Audio

I have not tried it. It seems to be a solution from lucid, but maybe your system will find it favorable!

> **PulseAudio and Jack**
>
> Thanks to packagers, there is now a very easy way to get PulseAudio
>   and Jack working together. First of all, install the package
>   pulseaudio-module-jack
>
> ```
> sudo apt-get install pulseaudio-module-jack
> ```
>
> It should work without any other tweak.